# How to use package.json scripts to copy files with specific file extension

Tags: npm, package.json, build-tools

I am trying out npm as a build tool.

One stumbling block I have encountered is that I need to copy javascript files from one folder to another. The source folder contains typescript files, javascript files and map files, but in the target folder I am only interested in javascript files.

I do not want to make a copy-statement for each file, but would like to copy all .js files. Also, my source folder contains subfolders that also contains javascript files. These need to be copied as well, and maintain the subfolder structure.

What I have tried is using [NCP](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) with a filter, but I cannot get the filter to work. I have tested the regex used in the filter and it appears to work fine. The test was done at [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com) with regular expression `.*\.js$` and test-strings like `main.ts`, `main.js` `main.js.map` etc, and only the .js strings were matched.

My package json contains the following (abbreviated):

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "copy": "ncp scripts wwwroot/scripts --filter=\".*(\\\\.js$)\"" 
    }, 
    "devDependencies": { 
        "ncp": "2.0.0.0" 
    }
}
```

Since my regex is in a string in a string I have double-escaped it. I have also tried other variations, for example:

```
--filter=/.*\.js$/g       - compilation error
--filter=/.*\\.js$/g      - no files copied
--filter=\".*\\.js$\"     - no files copied
--filter=\"/.*\\.js$/g\"  - no files copied
(no filter)               - all files copied
```

I am in no way married to NCP. If something else works better then I will use that.

So: How do I, inside package.json's scripts section copy only files with a speific extension to another folder? I am pretty sure I have overlooked something blindingly obvious...

Answer (score 102, accepted):

*Warning!  The cpx package appears to be abandoned. cpy-cli, copyfiles, and other solutions are listed in comments here or answers, below.*

[cpx](https://github.com/mysticatea/cpx) might be a good substitution.

It has a CLI, allows you to use globs instead of regex, can preserve the directory tree, and is relatively up-to-date as I write this....

Comment: Perfect. Now my script is "copy": "cpx \"scripts/**/*.js\" wwwroot/scripts", with the devDependency "cpx": "1.3.1".
It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: At now cpx seems to be abondened and has open vulnerabilities in the dependencies. I would suggest to use [cpy-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/cpy-cli) based on [cpy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/cpy).

Comment: I think [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp) might be a good substitute since cpx now seems to be abandoned. It's async and does recursive file and directory copying.

Comment: The last release was 3 years ago. Looks like it is abandoned. It has vulnerabitlies

Answer (score 47):

There's also npm module called `copyfiles`
https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/copyfiles

E.g. to copy all `*.css` files from the `./src` folder to the `./styles` folder:

```
copyfiles --flat src/*.css styles
```

Comment: Why not just `cp -R`? I'm using `cp -R ./email/templates ./build/email` and just curious about your solution.

Comment: @Woppi my reasoning would be, because it uses OS commands, which might not work on other OS's.

Answer (score 14):

Quick compatibility build script (also works on Windows):

```
"build": "react-scripts build && mv build docs || move build docs",
```

Comment: this will MOVE not COPY

Comment: So just change it to `cp build docs || copy build docs`

Comment: any drawbacks in using this command? can I use this with `&&` to chain commands in both windows and ubuntu?

Comment: @DeepakThomas "'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,". Your solution seems to be platfrom specific.

Answer (score 5):

```
@powershell copy \"D:/Path/untitled.txt\"  destionation-file.txt"
```

Comment: @JasonAller Powershell is available cross platform https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7#where-can-i-install-powershell

Comment: It would be useful to edit the answer to include that information and also to note how systems that don't have PowerShell installed will react to this line of code and if there is a way to mitigate that.

Answer (score 3):

Windows users:

```
// Copy file
xcopy c:\workfile d:\test

// Copy folders incl. sub folders
xcopy <source> <destination> /e

// If folder name has space in name use double quotes
xcopy c:\workfile “d:\test new”
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)

Answer (score 1):

You can use gulp.js for this.
Write a gulp task to isolate only the js files (/path/to/files/*.js) and move it to destination of your choice.
It will require only a few lines of code.
Include that in the script section of package.json if necessary.

The link to gulp.js : https://gulpjs.com/

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('jscopy', function(){
  return gulp.src('client/templates/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
});
```

Comment: Adding Gulp as a dependency just for copying files is a bit overdone. If you already/still use gulp, it could be an option.

Comment: Yeah if someone is using something like webpack they wouldn't want to add gulp to just use copy.

Answer (score 1):

ncp copies recursively, therefore before copying files it will check whether directory matches filter or not, e.g.:

```
d:\path\to\app\src\server
d:\path\to\app\src\server\middleware
d:\path\to\app\src\server\middleware\cool-middleware.js
d:\path\to\app\src\server\middleware\cool-middleware.js.map
```

So your regex must matches all these paths and your file also

Answer (score 0):

I am able to just use cp in my script command:

```
"build": "npx babel src --out-dir dist && cp ./src/*.css ./dist",
```

This will work if you have your distribution package already inside the /dist folder.  You can also add another command to copy that over, then even run the publish command.

`I use this in Git bash in windows which has the cp command available.  The comments are correct that you will need this in your underlying shell/command prompt.  It should be able to be modeled and updated for your OS.`

Comment: doesn't this require the `cp` npm package?

Comment: Doesn't work in windows?

Comment: @RuanMendes use `cp ./src/*.css ./dist || copy ./src/*.css ./dist` use cp and copy both with Or Condition, cp works for linux, mac and copy will work for windows

Answer (score 0):

[@KostovV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10617254/kostovv) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70432283/9310852) but adapted for json string and relative path

`"build": "nest build && xcopy \".\\myFolder0\" \".\\myFolde1\\sub\"",`

Answer (score 0):

I use the [shk package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx) it is a wrapper around ShellJS Unix commands.

Install shk as devDependencies and create a new script task:

```
"scripts": {
    "copy": "shx cp wwwroot/scripts/*.js ../destinationFolder" 
}
```