# npm copy script does not work on Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, deployment

I have sapui5 project and I want to run the following npm script in my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "flatten": "copy -r \\dist\\resources\\test\\commonjslib\\* dist",
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
commonjslib
  > .che
  > controls
  > dist
    > resources
      > test
        > commonjslib
  > ...
  > ...
  > ...
  > package.json
```

Now when I run ***npm run flatten***, I always receive the following error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

When I run the same command in the powershell terminal in VSCode, then it works.

I mean the directory is there, otherwise the commands would not work in powershell either.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out that I had to use the **@powershell** key in front of the command:

```
"scripts": {
   "flatten": "@powershell copy -r \\dist\\resources\\test\\commonjslib\\* dist",
}
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61317319/7719971

Comment: This command worked for me, without the @ symbol. Not sure what it does exactly.